# writing in a text file OpenCV visual studio

Tags: opencv, file-io

How can you write a element in a array into a  text file in OpenCV visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::ofstream f("C:/file_to_write_to.txt");

// writing element my_matrix[10, 10] to file.  assuming it's a float.
f << my_matrix.at<float>(10, 10) << std::endl;
f.close();
```